# duplicate symbol __ZN4ArmeC1Ev error in c++

Tags: c++, qt, g++

I am new in c++ programmation on Qt.
I do two classes Personnage and Arme.
I have 5 files Personnage.h, personnage.cpp, Arme.h and Arme.cpp

Arme.h

```
#ifndef ARME_H
#define ARME_H
#include<iostream>
class Arme
{
public:
Arme();
Arme(int m_idArme,std::string m_nomArme);
void armeAffich() const;
public:
int idArme;
std::string nomArme;
};
#endif // ARME_H
```

Arme.cpp

```
#include "Arme.h"
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
Arme::Arme():idArme(0),nomArme(0)
{

}
Arme::Arme(int m_idArme,string m_nomArme)
{
idArme=m_idArme;
nomArme=m_nomArme;
}

void Arme::armeAffich() const
{
cout<<"identifiant d'arme"<<idArme<<endl;
cout<<"nom d'arme"<<nomArme<<endl;
}
```

Personnage.h

```
#ifndef PERSONNAGE_H
#define PERSONNAGE_H
#include "Arme.h"
class Personnage
{
Personnage(std::string nom,std::string prenom);
Personnage();
~Personnage();
void affichPers() const;
public:
std::string nomPers;
std::string prenomPers;
Arme *arme;
};
#endif // PERSONNAGE_H
```

Personnage.cpp

```
#include "Arme.h"
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
Arme::Arme():idArme(0),nomArme(0)
{

}
Arme::Arme(int m_idArme,string m_nomArme)
{
idArme=m_idArme;
nomArme=m_nomArme;
}

void Arme::armeAffich() const
{
cout<<"identifiant d'arme"<<idArme<<endl;
cout<<"nom d'arme"<<nomArme<<endl;
}
```

and in the main.cpp file, iput two instructions just for compiling.

```
#include"Personnage.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello word!";
    return 1;
}
```

When I compiling i get these errors:

```
duplicate symbol __ZN4ArmeC1Ev in:
    Arme.o
    Personnage.o
duplicate symbol __ZN4ArmeC2Ev in:
    Arme.o
    Personnage.o
duplicate symbol __ZN4ArmeC1EiSs in:
    Arme.o
    Personnage.o
duplicate symbol __ZN4ArmeC2EiSs in:
    Arme.o
    Personnage.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK4Arme10armeAffichEv in:
    Arme.o
    Personnage.o
ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ExempleClasses] Error 1
18:55:46: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project ExempleClasses (kit: Desktop Qt 5.2.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

Any help please?

Comment: `echo '__ZN4ArmeC1Ev' | c++filt` gives `Arme::Arme()`, the constructor of `class Arme`

Answer (score 5):

In your post:

Personnage.cpp

```
#include "Arme.h"
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
Arme::Arme():idArme(0),nomArme(0)
{

}
```

Surely you don't really want to repeate `Arme::Arme` in Personage.cpp?